# easy_install ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

Tags: python, makefile, easy-install, buildout

I'm trying to buildout in isolated enviroment and I got this error:

```
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
An error occurred when trying to install djangorestframework-csv 1.3.3. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing django.
  Getting distribution for 'djangorestframework-csv'.
Error: Couldn't install: djangorestframework-csv 1.3.3
make: *** [bin/django] Error 1
```

I tried googling and found that this exact same issue was reported 5 days ago:

https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv/issues/18

This error also occurs when you try to

```
easy_install djangorestframework-csv==1.3.3
```

After a little bit more googling I found out that this error happens when there are errornous .pyc files.

This guy who reported the issue says that he solved this error by removing pycache. I tried searching pycache and removing all folders called `__pycache__` however it didn't help. Any ideas how to solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whomever created the distribution accidentally *included* the `__pycache__` directory in the tarball.

If you are using the `download-cache` option in your buildout, you can fix this by opening the downloaded `djangorestframework-csv-1.3.3.tar.gz` file and deleting the offending directory.

Find the file in your `${buildout:download-cache}/dist` directory, and repackage it without the offending directory:

```sh
tar xzvf djangorestframework-csv-1.3.3.tar.gz
rm -rf djangorestframework-csv-1.3.3/rest_framework_csv/__pycache__/
tar czvf djangorestframework-csv-1.3.3.tar.gz djangorestframework-csv-1.3.3
```

Now run your buildout again, and it'll use the fixed cached file.

Unfortunately, we cannot use `find-links` here to point to the fixed distribution as it'll only be used when the `index` (e.g. PyPI by default) does not have the package as well.

Comment: I cant find my buildout download-cache directory. Where could it be located ?

Comment: @Marijus: You need to have the option enabled; add `download-cache` to the `[buildout]` section. If you want a central location, create a `.buildout` directory in your home directory and anything in `~/.buildout/default.cfg` will be included in all buildout runs; you could put it there too for a global cache. See [user defaults](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/2.2.1#user-defaults).